# Apache Camel 3.0.1 can not start and consuming router to FTPs folder

Tags: java, spring-boot, ftp, apache-camel, ftps

I'm using Apache Camel FTP 3.0.1 and Spring Boot to connect and listen file created events on FTPs remote folder. It's work with my local FTP server (I'm not use yet FTPs on my docker local). But It can not start and consume router when I connect to FTPs server.

Here is my code :

```
@Component
public class ListenerSyncDataRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ListenerSyncDataRouter.class);

    @Autowired
    ListenerSyncDataFileProcessor listenerSyncDataFileProcessor;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("ftps://user@ftps_server_ip:21/ReceiveDataFile/Processing?password=xxx&ftpClient.trustStore.file=keys/diode.jks&ftpClient.trustStore.password=xxx&passiveMode=true&include=.*.xml&filter=#ftpFileFilter&move=ReceiveDataFile/Temp&maxMessagesPerPoll=200&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true&soTimeout=3000")
                .log("${body}")
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Processing ${id}")
                .process(listenerSyncDataFileProcessor)
                .end();
    }
}
```

I got abnormal logs as :

```
[INFO ] 2021-01-23 19:58:31.413 [main] SpringBootRoutesCollector - Loading additional Camel XML routes from: classpath:camel/*.xml
[INFO ] 2021-01-23 19:58:31.413 [main] SpringBootRoutesCollector - Loading additional Camel XML rests from: classpath:camel-rest/*.xml
[INFO ] 2021-01-23 19:58:31.420 [main] SpringBootCamelContext - Apache Camel 3.0.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
[INFO ] 2021-01-23 19:58:31.421 [main] JmxManagementStrategy - JMX is enabled
[INFO ] 2021-01-23 19:58:31.650 [main] SpringBootCamelContext - StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
```

The logs stop at `Apache Camel 3.0.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting` and not start and consumming for router.

Here is normal logs with my local FTP server :

FTP URI for connect local FTP server : `ftp://ftpuser@localhost:21/files?filter=%23ftpFileFilter&include=.*.xml&move=files%2Ftemp&passiveMode=true&password=xxxxxx`

```
[INFO ] 2021-01-23 19:53:45.474 [main] SpringBootRoutesCollector - Loading additional Camel XML routes from: classpath:camel/*.xml
[INFO ] 2021-01-23 19:53:45.474 [main] SpringBootRoutesCollector - Loading additional Camel XML rests from: classpath:camel-rest/*.xml
[INFO ] 2021-01-23 19:53:45.481 [main] SpringBootCamelContext - Apache Camel 3.0.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
[INFO ] 2021-01-23 19:53:45.481 [main] JmxManagementStrategy - JMX is enabled
[INFO ] 2021-01-23 19:53:45.727 [main] SpringBootCamelContext - StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
[INFO ] 2021-01-23 19:53:46.047 [main] SpringBootCamelContext - Route: route1 started and consuming from: ftp://ftpuser@localhost:21/files?filter=%23ftpFileFilter&include=.*.xml&move=files%2Ftemp&passiveMode=true&password=xxxxxx
[INFO ] 2021-01-23 19:53:46.090 [main] SpringBootCamelContext - Route: route2 started and consuming from: ftp://ftpuser@localhost:21/logs?filter=%23ftpFileFilter&include=.*.json&move=logs%2Ftemp&passiveMode=true&password=xxxxxx
[INFO ] 2021-01-23 19:53:46.093 [main] SpringBootCamelContext - Total 2 routes, of which 2 are started
[INFO ] 2021-01-23 19:53:46.094 [main] SpringBootCamelContext - Apache Camel 3.0.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.613 seconds
[INFO ] 2021-01-23 19:53:46.099 [main] ListenerApplication - Started ListenerApplication in 3.811 seconds (JVM running for 4.866)
Directory Change Listener running...
```

It's not get log for start and consuming router as run with FTP local so that It can not register router and listen file created events on FTPs folder.

What's wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to investigate if **ReceiveDataFile** is a directory inside the FTP user's home directory.

As stated in the [Camel FTP component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/ftp-component.html) :

> Absolute path is not supported. Camel translates absolute path to
> relative by trimming all leading slashes from directoryname. There’ll
> be WARN message printed in the logs.

Comment: Thanks for answer Alex, I've already use relative path for ReceiveDataFile. My directories tree on FTPs server as below :
`home/ftpuser/ftp/ReceiveDataFile/Processing`

I've tried to use /ftp/ReceiveDataFile/Processing path. But I got same result

Comment: Hello @AcidBurn.
Could you make a test to certify the connectivity to this server (using Telnet, for example). 
Maybe increasing log level to DEBUG or TRACE can help you to diagnose too.
At first I do not consider the connectivity problem because I think an error would be logged by Camel but this may not be the case when you are using FTP: https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-do-i-handle-failures-when-consuming-for-example-from-a-ftp-server.html

Comment: I found the problems with random range ports of ftps protocol, It use a range ports from 10000 to 11000 for random port before forward to 21 port. It need be open for IP source. Thanks Alex